Добавить название категории в класс body WordPress
Почему не работает этот код?
function my_body_class_filter( $classes ) {
    $post = get_post();
    $cat = get_the_category($post->ID);
   if ( $post ) {
       $classes[] = $cat->slug;
      }

    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class_filter' );

Пытаюсь добавить добавить название категории в класс body WordPress через файл темы function.php.
Такой код, например, работает:
function my_body_class_filter( $classes ) {
    $post = get_post();
    $cat = get_the_category($post->ID);
   if ( $post ) {
       $classes[] = $post->post_title;
      }

    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class_filter' );

Если пытаться добавить $cat->slug или $cat->name, ничего не выходит.

Разобрался
   function my_body_class_filter( $classes ) {
    $post = get_post();
    $category_detail = get_the_category($post->ID);

    foreach($category_detail as $cd){
    if ( $post ) {
       $classes[] = $cd->cat_name;
      }
}
    return $classes;
    }

add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class_filter' );


Лучше такого не делать и не переполнять классами которые не применяються на странице.  Проверку на страницах категорий можна реализовать через is_category()
